# ORA-00913: too many values Error (Even though I have checked my table and entries)

Tags: oracle10g, ora-00913

Here's is the table :

```
create table Student(
    student_id char(6) primary key,
    name varchar(10) not null,
    department char(20),
    grade char(6),
    percentage smallint,
    contact_no char(12),
    address varchar(50)
 );
```

This is what I'm inserting :

```
insert into Student
values ('ST-01','Zain','coe','A+',74,'9999777865','New Delhi');
```

Why ORA-00913: too many values error when I'm not inserting extra values ?

Comment: [Cannot repeat](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9f0fa/1).

Comment: Could you re-create the tables in SQL*Plus and display the output... this appears to be correct (though your use of smallint, char and varchar is kind of strange and you're inserting a character into your smallint column).

Comment: Buddy... I'm inserting 74 which is a integer....

Comment: It's good coding style to explicitely list the columns in the insert statement: `insert into student (student_id, ...)`. If you do, you probably see the problem right away.

Comment: @Noel: `varchar` will be replaced to `varchar2` (for over 20 years now). I seriously doubt that Oracle will ever change that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : Now after writing this :
insert into Student(student_id,name,department,grade,percentage,contact_no,address)
values ('ST-01','Zain','coe','A+',74 ,'9999777865','New Delhi');

The Error is : ORA-00904: "ADDRESS": invalid identifier

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson it's working there fine [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9f0fa/1/0) 'code'

Comment: @user2326894 Yes, that was what I said, I cannot repeat the problem you're describing, the SQL in your question is working well.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Buddy the error is coming on Oracle 10 G EE....

Comment: You are not inserting into the table that you think you are inserting into.

Comment: @DavidAldridge Thnx a ton Man... :)